# Retrieving data from a WPF datagrid solutions one works, one does not

Tags: wpf, datagrid, row

I found a couple solutions online

This one fails, but several posts say it should work.
I get an error stating that "Media_Tracks_Grid.ItemsSource" is null

```
foreach (ItemCollection  dr in Media_Tracks_Grid.ItemsSource)
{
  MessageBox.Show(dr[0].ToString());
}
```

This one works. I derived it from this export video.
https://youtu.be/7oTcMeSMjO8

```
for (int x = 0; x < Grid.Items.Count; x++)
{
 for (int i = 0; i < Grid.Columns.Count; i++)
 {
   TextBlock Item_Value = Grid.Columns[i].GetCellContent(Grid.Items[x]) as TextBlock;
   MessageBox.Show(Item_Value.Text);
 }
}
```

can anybody tell me why the first one does not work?

Comment: I guess, you didn't use ItemsSource, and added items directly into Items. `foreach (ItemCollection dr in Grid.Items)` should work (probably)

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. So ItemsSource  is a collection where a table has been passed to it so instantiates a ItemsSource collection. Not sure which method is more efficient then code wise. In one case you have to build the source to use the ItemsSource method. The other you can just add the items and then use the second method to retrieve your data. Not a lot of standard approaches out there on how best to use it. I'm using an API that lends itself to adding each item to my datagrid.

Comment: "Not a lot of standard approaches out there on how best to use it" - the recommended approach is MVVM: you create a view model which holds all data necessary for view, and then do bindings: `DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Collection_from_API}"`. it is not possible to create Binding for Items